# Update rows cell from another table by matching IDs

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi i have two tables ...

Acctive table:

> SELECT * FROM 36496839_radioamater.skladovekarty00006;

```
CISLO    NAME
1        NULL
2        NULL
3        NULL                  (other cells)
4        NULL
5        NULL
```

Helpfull table

> SELECT * FROM 36496839_radioamater.skladovekarty00008;

```
CISLO    NAME
1        one
4        four
3        tree                  (other cells)
```

And i need create a SQL code which find first row from table00008 in table00006 and copy value in NAME by matching CISLO

result:

```
CISLO    NAME
1        one
2        NULL
3        tree                  (other cells)
4        four
5        NULL
```

and thus need to remodel an additional 12 000 rows

Can anyone help me I have desperately
Thx, Martin

Comment: There is no such thing as a "first row" in a table (tables represent sets which are inherently unordered).  Can you guarantee that there is only one matching row?

Comment: `update ... join ... on ...` will probably do the trick.

Comment: Is the SQL different? And where is the database mentioned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
update 36496839_radioamater.skladovekarty00006 d
join 36496839_radioamater.skladovekarty00008 s on s.CISLO = d.CISLO
set d.NAME = s.NAME
```

Comment: thx ... all works ... i love you :)